# How to prove the convexity of the exponential function?

Tags: convex-analysis, exponential-function

How to prove that the convexity of exponential function?

It is not allowed to use second derivative of $e^x$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that $e^x$ is convex?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702241/how-to-prove-that-ex-is-convex)

Comment: Second derivative is everywhere nonnegative.

Answer (score 6):

This means you prove: if $a<b$, then for all $t$ such that $0\le t\le 1$,

$$\begin{align*}
f(ta+ (1-t)b) \leq tf(a) + (1-t)f(b)&\iff e^{ta+(1-t)b} \leq te^a+ (1-t)e^b\\
&\iff x^t\cdot y^{1-t} \leq tx+(1-t)y\\
&\iff r^t \leq tr + 1 - t\\
&\iff r^t - tr \leq 1 - t\\
&\iff t - tr \leq 1 - r^t\\
&\iff t \leq \dfrac{1-r^t}{1-r}
\end{align*}$$

with $x = e^a$, $y = e^b$, $r = \dfrac{x}{y}$, $0 < x < y$, and $0 < r < 1$.

Comment: Yeah I used it but how to prove this equality? I wanna prove it like we proved x². I mean in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702241/how-to-prove-that-ex-is-convex) by @FlyByNight

Comment: Is it just only way to prove it?